# Not able to exclude certain criteria on the basic search results using MarkLogic Structured Query

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

Not able to exclude the `sectionName = "PI"` criteria on the basic search results using MarkLogic Structured query.
example- Consider these two documents in DB.

*test1.json*

```
{
   "id" : "101",
   "sectionName" : "PI",
    "name" : "Myself",
   "emailId" : "aaa@gmail.com" 
}
```

*test2.json*

```
{
   "id" : "101",
   "sectionName" : "GD",
    "name" : "Prof",
   "emailId" : "aaa@gmail.com" 
}
```

Below is the sample code I tried:

```
"not-query":{  
   "value-query":{  
      "json-property":"sectionName",
      "text":["PI"],
      "term-option":["exact"]
   }
}
```

Resulset still displays the document containing sectionName="PI" i.e test1.json is not excluded.

Kindly suggest in this.

Adding search_Document_test xml.

```xml
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
<search-option>unfiltered</search-option>
<page-length>1</page-length>
<term apply="term">
<empty apply="all-results">
</empty>
<term-option>case-sensitive</term-option>
<term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
<term-option>diacritic-insensitive</term-option>
</term>
<grammar>
<quotation>"</quotation>
<implicit>
<cts:and-query strength="20" xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
</cts:and-query>
</implicit>
<starter strength="30" apply="grouping" delimiter=")">(</starter>
<joiner strength="10" apply="infix" element="cts:or-query" tokenize="word">OR</joiner>
<joiner strength="30" apply="infix" element="cts:near-query" tokenize="word">NEAR</joiner>
<joiner strength="30" apply="near2" consume="2" element="cts:near-query">NEAR/</joiner>
<joiner strength="50" apply="constraint">:</joiner>
<joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="LT" tokenize="word">LT</joiner>
<joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="LE" tokenize="word">LE</joiner>
<joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="GT" tokenize="word">GT</joiner>
<joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="GE" tokenize="word">GE</joiner>
<joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="NE" tokenize="word">NE</joiner>
</grammar>
<sort-order direction="descending">
<score>
</score>
</sort-order>
<constraint name="Collection">
<collection></collection>
</constraint>
<extract-document-data selected="include">
<extract-path>/URI</extract-path>
</extract-document-data>
</options>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which API you're using to execute the search, but likely the problem is that your search is running unfiltered. Unfiltered is faster, but can yield false positives.

You can learn more about filtered vs unfiltered search [here](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_98851) and [here](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/unfiltered).

If you're using the Search API (search:search) or the REST Client API, you can control whether or not the search is filtered via a query option.

If you're using the JSearch API, there's a filter method on the various query objects. For example, [DocumentsSearch.filter](http://docs.marklogic.com/DocumentsSearch.filter).

Comment: Thanks, I have used search API. The Rest API url used is     
 abc.net:8081/v1/search?format=json&pageLength=10&start=1&options=search_ Document_test&structuredQuery={"search":{"query":{"queries":[{"not-query":{"value-query":{"json-property":"sectionName","text":["PI"]}}}]},"options":{"search-option":["unfiltered","format-json"],"return-results":true}}} .                                                      Is there any persistent way to achieve the required result??. Can we do some changes in xml file??   I have also updated the search_Document_test Xml in the question.

Comment: If you don't want false positives, you need to use "filtered", not "unfiltered".

If by "a persistent way to achieve the required result", you mean your search options, then yes. The REST Client API enables you to store them in the database and reference them by name in your search requests. See the following topic on configuring query options: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_48838.

Comment: I tried with filtered option as well. The query used  is -                                
 abc.net/v1/search?format=json&pageLength=1&start=1&options=search_option_test&structuredQuery=
{"search":{"query":{"queries":[{"not-query":{"word-query":{"json-property":"sectionName", "text":["PI"], "term-option":["case-insensitive"]}}]}, "options":{"search-option":["filtered", "format-json"], "quality-weight":0, "return-facets":true, "return-results":true}}}&q=PI .                                                        
 Its returning PI in the resultset.